# Run a systemd timer only when network traffic is low

Tags: networking, linux-networking, systemd

I would like to run a systemd timer daily, with lax time accuracy. However, I would want the timer to run only if the network is continuous idle/low load (for at least 2 minutes).

Is there any way to accomplish this without resorting to an external script that checks network traffic for a long period of time?